# Should I use Dependency Injection or not in order to have a good design and testable code?

Tags: java, c++, dependency-injection, architecture

I have a class that represents an image: it's called `Photography`.

The constructor looks like this:

```
Photography::Photography(QString originalPath, QString appDirectory) {
    this.originalPath = originalPath;
    this.appDirectory = appDirectory;
}
```

The class contains many methods like `getTitle()`, `getCaption()`, `getSize()`, `isHorizontal()` etc.

There's a `public` method called `getThumbnailPath()` that looks like this:

```
QString Photography::getThumbnailPath() {

    if (previewPath == "") {
        previewPath = appDirectory + "//cache//"+  getHash() +"-thumb.jpg";
    }

    return previewPath;
}
```

This method, internally, calls a `getHash()` method:

```
QString Photography::getHash() {

    if (myHash == "") {

        QCryptographicHash hash(QCryptographicHash::Md5);
        QByteArray result = hash.hash(originalPath.toUtf8(), QCryptographicHash::Md5);
        QString hashResult(result.toHex());

        myHash  =  hashResult;
    }

    return myHash;
}
```

What I'm wondering is if the `getHash()` method belongs to the `Photography`class, or should be in its own `HashGenerator` which I should inject into the `Photography` class.

However, I don't want to inject a lot of parameters in the `Photography` constructor just to make the class testable.

In this case I'm facing the testing of the `getThumbnailPath()` method if I don't have control over the method that generates the hash I can't test the `getThumbnailPath()` method.

Comment: Why can't you test `getThumbnailPath`? I assume `QCryptographicHash` is deterministic.

Comment: yes, it is but is it a good practice to write the test knowing, from the outside, the algorithm used internally for generating the hash? You mean I should generate a few hashes and use those as tests?

Comment: having getHash inside Photography also violates [Single Responsiblity Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Also, you may consider grouping all the config parameters of Photography class as some class PhotoConfig to aggregate relevant and coherant parameters together, this avoids passing down multiple parameters.

Comment: Thanks Arun, yes, please see my comment on the answer by @whitecoffee, thanks.

Comment: Welcome @Stephen H. Anderson, you may consider reading [Martin Fowler](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html)

Answer (score 0):

"However, I don't want to inject a lot of parameters in the Photography constructor just to make the class testable."

Being **testable** is a good quality of any piece of code. But more so you are **decoupling** responsibility and making the code more maintainable by associating hashing with the hashing generator.

Also this now means u can independently test hashing without the class Photography. Its now **unit** testable hashing given a path for example without involving Photography

Comment: I agree with the decoupling of responsibility, as I never liked a Photography object to know how to generate a hash. But, what about that class, it would only be a little method in a little class.

Comment: Something I would also like to ask to see what others think (maybe my next question) is what about putting a setHashGenerator(hg) method instead of doing it via the constructor parameters. Haven't found info about this what the pros and cons could be.

Comment: Would the benefit of clarity and clear delegation of responsibility outweighs the 'little method in a little class' annoyance. Kinda a distraction dont you think away from what looks like a proper design etc.

Comment: @StephenH.Anderson, You don't necessarily need to use a class. If you're taking a class that has one function to use, you can take a function (and store it in `std::function`) instead. Anyway, if this injected hash implementation isn't an optional part of using the class, the constructor is preferred.

Comment: @Stephen H. Anderson, both constructor injection and setter injection are well known approaches of following Dependency Injection Principle. Setter injection gives the flexibility of configuring an instance of Photography class with different parameters to customize the behaviour on needs,

Comment: @StephenH.Anderson before you ask you should search along the lines of 'constructor versus setter getter' etc. This is one of the age old topics of arguement, and as usual "it always depends" and might end up being something preferential in most use case

Comment: "But, what about that class, it would only be a little method in a little class" among the most diehard OO aficionados, basically everything is reduced to "a little method in a little class"

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a good idea to take the hashing code out of the `Photography` class and you can test that independently but I wouldn't rush to inject that dependency into `Photography` unless you need more than one implementation of the hashing algorithm.

I think it is ok for the `Photography` class to have a dependency on the hashing code, which could be something as simple as a free function. The hashing algorithm is already effectively exposed via the `getThumbnailPath` member function so I don't see there is a particular problem with generating an expected hash to use in tests for `getThumbnailPath`.

Answer (score 0):

You should give everything **that you need to change** from outside[**context independence**] (giving at creation using a constructor or using a setter method. When you use the setting method, you should provide a default instance at constructor(not through parameters)) --- **Dependencies**(objects without which the constructed object do not makes sense) **should be provided through constructor.** Others could be given through setters.

NOTE: If you have to give too much helper object at constructor, then probably there are too much responsibility for the object. You should consider changing the design. (I think more than 8,9 parameter at constructor requires a redesign thinking)

I also think that what you need to change is not how the hash is computed. What you need to change is how ThumbnailPath is computed. Hence, you should use an interface like:

```
public interface ThumbnailGenerator{ //give a mock for the ThumbnailGenerator at testing.
  public ThumbnailPath generatePath(Object argumentToUseInGeneration);
}
```

instead of

```
public interface HashGenerator{
  public Object generateHash(Object argument);
}
```

NOTE: In java, hash calculation is within the object itself because hash calculation depends on the object state. (You could pass an helper object in calculating the hash but the hash method is within the object).